# uwsgi, multiple environment variables

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi, wsgi

I am using uWSGI to run a Django application on nginx. I have configured the server and all seems to be running well. What I would really like to be able to do is store the django secret key within the systems environment variables so it is not part of the settings.py file.

**I know that somewhere within the uwsgi options there is the ability to pass through multiple environment settings; but I cannot find this. Can someone please tell me how this is done.**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `uwsgi_param PARAM_NAME 'param_value';` then access with `request.environ['PARAM_NAME']`

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me was append to `wsgi.ini` file:

```
env = PARAM_NAME=param_value
```

Not needed to add `"` or `'` or end with semicolon.
If you don't know where is `xxx.ini` you can see nginx file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`